# jQuery each collection Set from Thymeleaf

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf, each

I am trying to get roles from the Set userRoles of the userTable object, but I get an error. How to properly get each role in jQuery? Then I want to transfer the role to modal to affix the role checkbox.

Exception:

```
jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]
at T (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
at fillingModal (users:294)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (users:139)
```

Script:

```
function fillingModal(userId, userUsername, newPassword, userRoles) {

    // alert(userId + ", " + userUsername + ", " + newPassword) //working

    //по id в модалку передаем параметры из тегов th: таймлифа
    $("#modal-id").text("Edit user Id: " + userId);
    $("#modal-username").val(userUsername);
    $("#modal-newPassword").val(newPassword);

    // data myUserRoles = userRoles
    $.each(userRoles, function (value) {
        if (this.value === "ROLE_USER") {
            // $("#modal-checkboxUser").val(roleUser)
            alert(value)
        }
        if (this.value === "ROLE_ADMIN") {
            // $("#modal-checkboxUser").val(roleAdmin);
            alert(value)
        }
    })
}
```

Thymeleaf:

```
<tr th:each="userTable : ${allUsers}">
<td th:text="${userTable.id}"></td>
<td th:text="${userTable.username}"></td>
<td>
    <!--впихиваем роли в столбец Роли-->
    <div th:each="role : ${userTable.roles}" th:text="${role}"></div>
</td>
<td>
    <!--модалка-->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
            data-target="#exampleModal"
            data-toggle="modal"
            th:data-userId="${userTable.id}"
            th:data-userUsername="${userTable.username}"
            th:data-newPassword="${newPassword}"
            th:data-roles="${userTable.roles}"
            onclick="fillingModal(this.getAttribute('data-userId'), this.getAttribute('data-userUsername'), this.getAttribute('data-newPassword'), this.getAttribute('data-roles'));">
        Edit
    </button>
    <a class="btn btn-primary"
       th:href="@{/admin/users/delete/{id}(id=${user.id})}"
       role="button">Delete</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to create custom arguments in Thymeleaf you have to use `th:args`, something like below:

```
<button th:args="data-userId=${userTable.id},data-roles=${userTable.roles}">Edit</button>
```

Note: I just showed a few `data-*` args above.

Now, `userTable.roles` returns a `Set` and a `.toString()` representation of a set is `[Elem1, Elem2...]` which is not understood by Javascript.

So you would have to convert the `Set` into a comma seperated String something like `Elem1,Elem2,...` this can be achieved by in Java 8 and above

```
set.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","))
```

or in Java 7 and below using Apache commons `StringUitls` library.

Then in Javascript you would split the string on `","` to get the array back and then iterate the way you are doing now.

```
roles.split(",")
```

Comment: Is there a .contains () method on jQuery to find the substring I need in the [Elem1, Elem2] line?

Comment: MohamedSanaulla, your answer did not work (I'm talking about button)! Left as I had originally. But thanks to your answer about Set, I was able to parse a string with roles using jQuery .include ()! Thanks! Unfortunately, I realized that I can not put checkboxes in thymeleaf from js since thymeleaf works on the server side ...

Comment: Regarding `contains` method - its not the right way. And may also lead to bugs. Representing a collection as a collection in JS is the correct approach

Comment: My solution was for the query you posted - failure of using `$.each(userRoles, ...` and how to get roles back in jQuery.